# Calling public Dictionary with parameter

Tags: c#

I am trying to call the public dictionary into my main

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write(GetServiceOutput());
    Console.Write(ReadRecords('A'));

    Console.Read();
}

public Dictionary<string, string> ReadRecords(string type)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    var client = new AmazonRoute53Client();
    var request = new ListResourceRecordSetsRequest();
    var list = client.ListResourceRecordSetsAsync(request);

    foreach (var recordSet in list.Result.ResourceRecordSets)
    {
        var values = recordSet.ResourceRecords.Select(p => p.Value);
        result.Add(recordSet.Name, string.Join(",", values));
    }
    return result;
}
```

It cant find 'ReadRecords', but the class exists Can someone help? I am just confused on calling dictionary, trying to get my head around this.

Comment: `ReadRecords` should be static.

Comment: @Scott Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Main method is static while the ReadRecords method is non-static.  Add the static keyword to your ReadRecords method (if it is indeed static) in order to call it from Main directly.

Otherwise, you'd need to instantiate an instance of a class in Main and call the ReadRecords method of that class instance (as non-static)